# Why so few people?

Tags: discussion

OK, so I am fairly new to this site, being a refugee from seasoned advice.  But seriously, where is everyone.  I have been putting up questions, even answering them as I think that this is a great site.  How do we get more people through, and staying put?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Share the site and bring others in!  Really though, what it comes down to is the hard work of creating quality content, both questions and answers.   Our traffic has been slowly building.  We're considerably ahead of where we were a year ago, which was considerably ahead of where we were two years ago.

The number one source of traffic for StackExchange sites is web search results, and the StackExchange team has don a fantastic job of building a platform that surfaces relevant content to the search engines and regularly appears at the top of the search results.  In order to take advantage of that, get that traffic, and then turn some of eyeballs into committed community members who continue building our repository, we need to continue building the content base.

So, continue to do what you're doing, and tell people about the site as well.  It's a process, and it take awhile to build momentum, but we're headed in the right direction.

Comment: Hi, yes I might have been a bit 'harsh', and I do tell others about the site - and compared to other sites it is a youngster.  I noticed a comment about tags else where.  I seriously hope that the site carries on growing - and to be involved with Q&T's (not just G&T's!).  It's great all the work that you do...  It was meant as a troop rallier and nothing else - hope I didn't offend.

Comment: think I did my bit for the site on beta with my last question!

Answer (score 2):

Many sites do not seem to make it past small volume.

This site was expanded from just beer to hopefully bring in a larger audience a while ago.

I don't think fabricated questions grow a site as it feels fake.  But I am OK with users that fabricate questions.

I feel like this is welcoming site.

There are some sites that new users are not welcomed.

Comment: Confused - what do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

The problems are two-fold:

1. The majority of people aren't hobbyist drinkers
2. Alcohol is a shallow topic

No matter how well this site is advertised most people drink alcohol to get drunk, not to study the fine details of it, and so most people will just never be interested in a site like this.

The other part of it is that alcohol is a shallow topic. I've asked a fair number of questions in this area to date, but to be frank there just isn't a lot more that I want to know that would be appropriate for this site. And so the nature of not repeating questions on Stack Exchange means that activity is naturally slow here.

If anything I think this speaks to questions over why and how we define a site as 'beta'. To me this is a fairly mature community, but will likely never meet non-beta status just due to the nature of the topic. That doesn't mean that the section isn't interesting, worthwhile, valuable or in need of improvement.

Answer (score 1):

I think apart from Beers we could bring in another drinks , juices etc from liquid side too to increase the potential users .
What say ?

Comment: Can you expand a bit please?

Comment: Kind of addition of juices from veggies and fruits and other drinks.. in all a generic drinks section

Comment: I hear what you are saying - talking about what we 'mix' with our drinks, but not in the more traditional meaning of 'mixers'.  Have I got that right?  I believe that it would expand our horizons, however we don't want to incur the wrath of cooking and veggie sites.  I wonder what all the others think?

Comment: http://meta.alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/55/what-kinds-of-questions-will-keep-beer-se-active-relax-the-culture-against-bra?rq=1 

Have checked the above question ... My idea would work as most of the users are concerned about the beer site not evolving ... Need of Evolution i Guess .

Comment: I think you may have something BeerFreezer, would you like to expand your answer to include other drinks like pop drinks, energy drinks, tea and/or coffee?

Comment: Exactly my point @KenGraham , we could generalise it for drinks  like pop , energy , tea etc and let users decide based on new tags this would add more users from different strata of society

Comment: We could start with tea if for example  , let say , there are many  different types  of tea only in India which could let to different types of answers depending on  content type of each  tea and slowly gradually we could add another category of drinks as well if the first idea took off

Comment: A site isn't just a collection of topics; it's a community of users who come here because of shared interests.  The site scope expanded last year from beer to all forms of alcohol, which still seems like a cohesive group, but I don't think we can reason that any community has a shared interest in beer, vodka, margaritas, herbal teas, Gatorade, protein drinks, grapefruit juice, and whole milk.  That would be too broad and incoherent IMO, and also overlaps with Seasoned Advice and Coffee.  I think we need to work more to expand our current scope (with quality, of course).